Sticky cards overlap each other
The problem is that when I am scrolling, the cards overlap each other when they are stacked. I want the cards to remain in the same view and sort order and not reach the end of the container, so that one is higher than the other, but the headers are clickable. In this site it looks buggy, you can see here.
This is how its looks like on the site.



:root {
    --cards: 5;
    --cardHeight: 47vh;
    --cardTopPadding: 5.5em;
    --cardMargin: 2vw;
}

.card-container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#cards {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--cards), var(--cardHeight));
    gap: var(--cardMargin);
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--cards) * var(--cardTopPadding));
    margin-bottom: var(--cardMargin);
}

#card1 {
    --index: 1;
}
#card2 {
    --index: 2;
}
#card3 {
    --index: 3;
}
#card4 {
    --index: 4;
}
#card5 {
    --index: 5;
}

.card {
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
    padding-top: calc(var(--index) * var(--cardTopPadding));
}

#card1 .card-body {
    background-color: #52B2CF;
}
#card2 .card-body {
    background-color: #E5A36F;
}
#card3 .card-body {
    background-color: #9CADCE;
}
#card4 .card-body {
    background-color: #D4AFB9;
}
#card5 .card-body {
    background-color: #79bc5b;
}

.card-body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 750px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    height: var(--cardHeight);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
        position:relative;
}

h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        left:0px;
}
<div class="card-container">
        <ul id="cards">
            <li class="card" id="card1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="/pure-infinity-engagement-and-bridal/"><h2>Pure Infinity (Engagement & Bridal)</h2></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="card" id="card2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="/pure-classic/"><h2>Pure Classic</h2></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="card" id="card3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="/pure-shape/"><h2>Pure Shape</h2></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="card" id="card4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="/pure-fashion/"><h2>Pure Fashion</h2></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="card" id="card5">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="/pure-high-jewellery/"><h2>Pure (High Jewellery)</h2></a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



How can this be fixed?

Can you show a picture of expected behaviour? Because now - apart from the titles being too big, the effect is quite cool

you ca see here https://codepen.io/msgor86/pen/XWLZvZZ, i dont know why, but runned code in here is ugly. the problem is not in effect, I want the cards to have clickable titles when folded, but everything to stay the same.

On codepen, when I scroll the page down, some cards move higher than I suspect you want them to

Yes, there is something wrong there too, but on my site the cards stack evenly. I don't know why, but the problem is not that, but the overlapping of the headers of the above cards with the below cards. thats how its look like on site https://ibb.co/fSWVrYd

The titles aren't clickable, because you are adding padding-top to the cards. You should probably rather set similar values for the top property instead. Try top: calc(var(--index) * var(--cardTopPadding));, and see how you like the result. (Might need more fine-tuning regarding the actual values.)

Just remove position: absolute; from the <h2> tag, title will not overlap.

C3roe
thanks thats work for me, but at the end of card container they all stacked without padding, how can we fix it?
